# Military sf short story: something like super-infantry on a raid

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, military-sf

Maybe 20 or 30 years ago I read a short story recounting a futuristic raid (I suspect on another planet) on an enemy settlement by (I think) a handful of soldiers.  I think that they more or less run through a forest or jungle, too quickly and expertly to be intercepted.  I don't recall exactly what their mission is (possibly a specific assassination... not at all sure...), but they execute it with single-minded efficiency and return to base.  I think that their losses are minimal, perhaps zero.

As far as I can remember, one of the story's main points is for readers to realise that these guys are enhanced in some way:  biologically, chemically and/or cybernetically.  I have a feeling that this kind of mission is nevertheless so physically taxing (on whatever proportion of their system is still human) that these soldiers cannot be deployed often.

I *think* that the story ends with them returning to what amounts to a kind of storage, to recuperate or recharge for next time.  I think we are allowed to realise that these soldiers' conditioning is such that they have no concept of any other kind of human existence:  their entire world is these occasional missions.

I have been searching for this story for a few years now.  The author must have been well-known enough for the story to make it into a fairly high-profile anthology, but I now can't find it anywhere.

Comment: If I didn't know better I'd swear it sounds like the move [_Soldier_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldier_(1998_American_film)). Especially that recuperation bit.

Comment: @AthenaWidget  That's a fair guess, and I wish it were that simple.  _Soldier_ might well have been inspired to some extent by the tale (or they might share a common forebear), but the story certainly predates the film by a fair old while.

Comment: I was wondering about that, evidently the script pre-dated the move by about [15 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldier_(1998_American_film)#Production_notes), so...

Comment: Sounds familiar. I recall a story where it starts with soldiers in a mess hall getting drunk, then the call comes in and they are given a drug to sober them up instantly. During the mission they are drugged which makes their reactions super quick - essentially the world around them is in slow motion. My first thought was Arthur C Clark, but I can't find it at the moment. I can normally remember where I read most short stories, but this one is eluding me at the moment.

Comment: @Eborbob  At first glance (the mess hall bit, and given what I think I remember about these soldiers being resources with virtually no personality) I was going to say that this can't possibly be the story I'm after... but in fact you _might_ be onto something.

Comment: @Eborbob  It doesn't sound at all like Clarke to me, incidentally.  I suppose that that's because the story I have in mind seems to have as a central concern the kind of humane issue that someone like Drake or Haldeman (and to a lesser extent Dickson) tends to hide in military sf stories:  it is up to the capable reader, _not_ seduced by the story's surface derring-do, to intuit that these poor guys have absolutely no perspective beyond the supersoldiering that they have been bred (or conditioned, or whatever) to undertake.

Comment: @Eborbob  Personally I don't associate Clarke with military-flavoured sf to start with, and I also don't generally find him smuggling-in that kind of theme.  (Stuff like 'The Star' has very humane concerns, of course, but is also very much more on-the-nose.)

Comment: Whether or not the story I'm thinking of is the same as the one you are, it's now bugging me that I can't think of the title / author! If I get a few spare minutes over the next week I'll take a look through my collection and see if I can find it.

Comment: @Eborbob  I, too, am now intrigued to know which story has sparked your thinking!  I'd still give it a small-but-real chance of being the one I am trying to remember, but I'd like to know what it is in any case.  Amongst my (many) anthologies are a few specifically focussed on military sf, so there's a reasonable chance that I have it.

Comment: Well I finally had a chance to look through my collection, but unfortunately I've not been able to identify the story I was thinking of. I'll keep looking though.

Comment: @Eborbob  Thanks so much for continuing to check.  This tiny, tiny matter is starting to drive me nuts!  I am now wondering about just writing and publishing the story as I think remember it, purely in the hope of getting done for plagiarism.

Comment: I an pretty sure this story was by a British author.

Answer (score 7):

**Soldiers Running** by Brian W. Aldiss (1960)

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?410031

The soldiers are in a war which has dragged on for a long time. Various medications have been key to keeping the soldiers effective. If the soldiers had been getting drunk and are suddenly needed for a mission, there is a medication that will instantly sober them up.

The protagonist along with a small group of other soldiers have been selected to test a new combat drug, *Fast-Plus*. It is a sort of pep-pill that allow soldiers to move and react faster than ordinary human beings. They are given special firearms with hair-triggers suitable to fast reflexes. The pills are shaped like a boomerang and fit under the tongue until time comes to eat them.

The soldiers successfully perform a raid on an enemy building, but the drug has side effects. One soldier dies of a heart attack. Their sped-up reflexes and the sound of their firearms damage the other soldier's hearing.

Comment: I believe Winchell Chung has the answer. I am awarding him the bounty.